# Warning: message-spool operational status is not AD-Active

Tags: solace

I am using Solace VMR community edition version 8.1

Whenever I try to create a topic or queue on the VMR the warning message shows up.

I have tried following the guide on
http://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing-Routers/Configuring-Guaranteed-Msging.htm
but there is no command for allow-guaranteed-message-receive.

I have also tried to using SolAdmin to add the topic and error message says "unable to complete request because router is not active for Guaranteed Delivery"
This was working fine when I used version 8.0 on another machine. Is it due to the version update or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can view the state of the message-spool in SolAdmin by navigating to the 'Message Spool Configuration' view on the 'General' tab. The Operational Status of the message-spool must be AD-Active in order to use guaranteed messaging or to create a queue or topic endpoint.

If the operational status is showing as AD-Disabled, this means the message-spool has been administratively disabled. You can change this by selecting 'Manage Message Spool Status' from the drop down menu on the right and clicking the gear. There will be a pop up where you can enable the message spool.

If the operational status is showing AD-NotReady, you can scroll down to see the 'Last Failure Reason' which will give you more information about why the message-spool is not ready to become active.

By default when you initialize a new VMR in version 8.1, the message-spool will be AD-Active if the VMR was configured correctly.

Comment: The Operational status is showing AD-NotReady and last failure reason is N/A. So I'm guessing the VMR is just not set up correctly from the start?

Comment: An operational status of AD-NotReady with no Last Failure Reason could indicate a mistake in configuration procedures.

@chey You can try resolving this by issuing a message-spool reset to get the message-spool back to its original state. Note that this will remove any currently spooled message.
http://docs.solace.com/System-and-Software-Maintenance/Sys-Level-Msg-Spool-Admin-Tasks.htm?#Resettin